# How to search for keyword in entire project excluding specific folder in VsCode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a project `Project1` that contains the keyword `"crash"` in a bunch of files. Most of the occurrences of `"crash"` occur in the `build/` folder. Is there a way in VsCode to search for instances of `"crash"` in the whole project, excluding the `build/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the search icon, on the left of your screen, you will see a search bar. If you click on the `...` under the search bar, you will see advanced options, in which you can specify file to exclude.

In this field, you can use wildcard to exclude directory and files.

Here is an image of what to look for.

[image]